# Android - How to get bytes from file in order to send it

Tags: java, android

I need to make an Android app that choose a file (type apk) from device and send it to a webservice by HTTP post. 
The question is, how can I get bytes from file in order to send it?

I have done the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button1;
Button button2;
Intent intent;
String PathHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);

    //FileManager
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(requestCode){

        case 1:

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                //String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();
                PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, PathHolder , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

    }
}
}
```

Now, I have the filepath only.

Comment: Try this https://www.programcreek.com/2009/02/java-convert-a-file-to-byte-array-then-convert-byte-array-to-a-file/

Comment: It's very well explained but my application doesn's work. It searchs for file in its private folders while I want It get it from SDcard.

Comment: Then point to our external storage: `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "file.txt"`

Comment: I did         PathHolder = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath(); File file = new File(PathHolder);       but app crashes.

Comment: Check the crash log?